# BigO of permutation algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation

if wrote the following algorithm to generate all permutations without repetition but I have a hard time figuring out the BigO if it. I'm mostly interested in the time-complexity.

```
const permutationsWithoutRepetition = arr => {
  let permutations = [arr];

  for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length-2; i++) {
    permutations = permutations.map( permutation => {
        const fixed = permutation.slice(0,i);
        const variable = permutation.slice(i);

        return variable.map((_, idx) => [...fixed, ...variable.slice(idx), ...variable.slice(0,idx)]);
    }).flat();
  }

  return permutations;
}
```

What the algorithm does is put every element in the first place then fixate it at the first position. In the next iteration it does the same for n-1 elements and so on till only two elements are left.
I tried to visualize it like this. Maybe it helps.

[algorithm visualization for n=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phxfo.png)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan there's a `.map()` inside the `for` loop, looks like n-squared to me. *edit* wait there's a `.map()` *inside* the `.map()`. And all those spread operations, this is not O(n).

Comment: @Pointy that's why I said *Interesting*. Yes a `O(n2)` might be correcter than `O(n)` since the inner mapping is also over some `n`. You're correct.

Comment: @Pointy yes its for => map => map and the spread operations, thats why I have such a hard time getting my head around the BigO of this.

Comment: I'm not well versed with JS, but wouldn't generating all permutations be ```O(N!)```?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur algorithmic complexity is independent of implementation language generally. However, you are correct in that the number of permutations without repetition for a set of N things is N!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it filters down to O(n^3), since you have 3 major loops in your initial for loop and 2 map calls. I think we ignore the slices since they add complexity linearly, while the nested loops are exponential.

I'm not positive that we include the variable.map, so it could be O(n^2), but I don't think that's the case. In most cases I would just simplify it to polynomial complexity, unless it's a case where the degree matters.

Comment: I don't think it's exponential, it's a third-order polynomial

Comment: You're right, exponential would be O(3^n) rather than O(n^3). I get those mixed up.

Comment: I thought about O(n^3) but also was not sure about the last variable.map. Thanks